# Can't see the edge line in edit mode?

Tags: mesh

Blender 3.12

Connection address for problem demonstration:
https://www.ixigua.com/7142775731351716387?utm_source=xiguastudio&wid_try=1

The URL is a Chinese website watermelon video. I don't know whether it can be accessed outside China.

Status bar screenshot:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Problem Description:

1. Left click cannot select objects, box select cannot select objects.
2. If the object origin is hidden, the left button cannot select the object at all
3. If the object origin is displayed, the object can only be selected by clicking around the origin.
4. When you switch TO EDIT MODE, the dots AND faces are displayed normally. In edge mode, the edges are not displayed, but you can select and move the edges.

Hope enthusiastic netizens to help answer, where does the problem appear? Heartfelt thanks!!

The results of the latest attempt.
Completely uninstalled nonstandard blender addons, load the blender factory preferences and load factory settings startup file, but questions remain.

I lost all of my customizations, key Settings, interface Settings, path Settings since Blender started...

Do I have to completely uninstall all Blender installation files? Deep confusion and fear!!

Also, I tried to start another version of Blender locally and had the same problem.

Comment: 1. Did you reset the settings to factory values to check if the problem still appear?
2. Does it also happen in Blender 3.3 LTS ?

Comment: Not tried in Blender 3.3, not installed

Comment: Tried versions 2.93, 3.1

Comment: Resetting to appearance Settings won't fix the problem, it's already been tried